# Cannot press tab key in protected workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In review, protect tab, I have ticked everything and for some strange reason, I cannot seem to press the tab key when the workbook is protected.  Unfortunately I cannot find a solution to this.  I have tried unticking everything in protected mode and the issue remains.

Comment: does the ***RIGHT ARROW*** key behave the same way??

Comment: The tab key takes you to the next unlocked cell. Are any cells on your worksheet unlocked? If not, there's nowhere to tab to.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to select the cells where your tab need to land in, and make it unlocked. while protecting, enable selection of unlocked cells. that should do what you look for.